# Deck boards meet accent/seam board: gap or not?

Tags: wood, deck

I'm designing a 20'x12' deck with 5/4"x6" floor boards (pressure-treated northern fir), which will have a seam/accent board to break the 20' run into 2 x ~10' sections.  The accent is ~12' long, perpendicular to the 20' span.  I'm framing to ensure there is a decent drip-gap beneath where the boards butt against the accent.

My question is: should the ~10' floor boards butt snugly against the edge of the accent board, or should I leave a small gap between the chopped ends and the accent edge?